# google app engine proxy workaround

Tags: java, google-app-engine, proxy

I am trying to build a google app engine app in Java.  The app is trying to get information from another site.  On my computer I am behind a firewall and need to connect to the site through a proxy.  Google app engine does not allow the use of java.net.proxy.  Is there a way to configure eclipse so it knows that when I use URL.getContent() my local host will connect to that url through a proxy??

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [thread](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=544#c20) issue, there's a **patched jar** that allows you to connect through a Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no way to do this, at least with current release of the SDK. I've gone through suffering from this problem.

The workaround is to make your system inherently aware of proxy. For example, use VPN, or use iptables to configure your proxy on Linux system.

It seems when your use normal way to specify a proxy as with other Java application it will invoke a class not in the JRE white list of GAE/J.